# Issues with child page's display when using Frames

Tags: xaml, layout, uwp, uwp-xaml

## Problem

This is the layout of my main pane:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Communities.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Communities"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="Page_Loaded" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="48" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        ...
        <SplitView Grid.Row="1" Name="hamburgerMenu" OpenPaneLength="200" PaneBackground="#F02A2A2A">
            <SplitView.Pane>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="HamburgerItemClick">
...             </ListView>
            </SplitView.Pane>
            <Frame Name="frame" />
        </SplitView>
        <Grid Grid.RowSpan="3" Name="popupArea" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

the `frame` is where I load all my pages, so that the layout is always consistant.

Now, in most of my child pages I have defined `AppBar` control and attached it to the `BottomAppBar` property of that child page:

***PostView.xaml***

```
...
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarButton Label="Back" Icon="Back" Click="TryGoBack" />
        <AppBarButton Label="Refresh" Icon="Refresh" Click="TryRefreshComments" />
        <AppBarButton Label="Go to Community" Icon="Go" Click="TryOpenCommunity" />
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
...
```

Here's where the trouble starts. It works fine on PC, as the layout is mostly static on desktop. There are no software keyboards required most of the time etc. On mobile it's more problematic: [Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u10a.jpg)

## My thoughts

It seems like the frame that is used to display the child page is causing all sorts of problems. When the AppBar is defined in the main page it positions correctly.

I'd like to avoid the keyboard covering the textbox as well as the AppBar but I don't want to get rid of the `frame` control. I'd also prefer it if the page got "squished" when the keyboard shows up, instead of getting pushed upwards, but I'm not sure how to display the keyboard on the `frame` level, instead of the entire `MainPage`, default level.

What would be the best way to solve this situation?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As you know, if we set the `Page.BottomAppBar` in the root of the Page, there is no issue with Touch keyboard. It seems it is the best way to add the `Page.BottomAppBar`.

If you want to add the `Page.BottomAppBar` in the other page in the `Frame`, you should be able to customize your UI. The UWP provides similar behavior on the appearance of the touch keyboard by handling the [`Showing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242262) and [`Hiding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242260) events exposed by the [InputPane](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242255) object.

We can use the `InputPaneVisibilityEventArgs.OccludedRect` to get the region of the application's window that the input pane is covering.

For example:

```cs
public PostView()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Showing += PostView_Showing;
    InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Hiding += PostView_Hiding;
}

private void PostView_Hiding(InputPane sender, InputPaneVisibilityEventArgs args)
{
    MyTextBox.Margin = new Thickness(0, args.OccludedRect.Height, 0, 0);
}

private void PostView_Showing(InputPane sender, InputPaneVisibilityEventArgs args)
{
    MyTextBox.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, args.OccludedRect.Height);
}
```